# Issue with TCPClient listening service - Looks like it goes to sleep while connected

Tags: c#, multithreading, service, tcpclient

I have a situation with my TCPClient sessions.

**The Background:**

- I run a Bulk SMS service and we've recently switched from pulling to listening for new messages from my Network Mobile Operator (MNO)
- I have written a class to listen for new messages (see code below)
- I call the class 15 times as I need to have a thread running for each account that I have with the MNO
- Each thread sends through subscription info for the specific account and waits for messages
- When I run the code it calls & creates 15 threads and indicates that all threads are connected
- I stop and start (re-create) the 15 Threads every 60 mins. Every time I refresh, my logs indicate that each thread is connected correctly
- I need the listening service to up 24/7

**The problem:**

- Although the threads look like they are connected, I have situations where I test the service and no messages come through the listening service. It's almost like the threads have gone to sleep although the MNO indicates that all threads are connected
- What can I do to ensure that I always receive inbound messages?

Here's my code for the listening service.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using log4net;
using MessageManagerWinService.Util;
using MessageManagerWinService.DAL;
using MessageManagerWinService.Classes;
using System.Linq;


namespace MessageManagerWinService.MTNListener
{
public class Listener {
    internal static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Listener));

    private ManualResetEvent _stopEvent;
    private Thread _listenerThread;
    private bool _running;
    private bool _connected;
    private DateTime _lastSubscribe;
    private TcpClient _client;
    private NetworkStream _stream;

    public string _listenType { get; set; }
    public string _username { get; set; }
    public string _password { get; set; }

    public void Start() 
    {
        _stopEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        //_listenType = listenType.ToUpper();
        _listenerThread = new Thread(ListenerThreadProc);
        _running = true;
        _listenerThread.Start();
    }

    public void Stop() {
        _running = false;

        try
        {
            _client.Close();
            log.Info(_listenType + " Client Closed - " + " - " + DateTime.Now);
        }
        catch (Exception) 
        {
            log.Info("Tried Closing Client - Client not open - " + _listenType + " - " + DateTime.Now);
        }

        Thread.Sleep(1000); // or more
        if (_listenerThread.IsAlive)
        {
            log.Info("Aborting thread - " + _listenType + " - " + DateTime.Now);
            _listenerThread.Abort();
        }
    }

    private void Reconnect() 
    {
        int srvInd = 0;

        while (_running && !_connected) 
        {
            string addr = "";

            if (_listenType == "USSD")
            {
                addr = AppSettings.Instance.ReceiveGatewayUSSD[srvInd];
            }
            else if (_listenType == "ACCOUNTS")
            {
                addr = AppSettings.Instance.ReceiveGatewayAccounts[srvInd];
            }

            log.Info("Connecting to " + _listenType +" IP Address : " + addr + "...");

            var ipAddr = addr.Split(':')[0];
            var port = Int32.Parse(addr.Split(':')[1]);

            _client = new TcpClient();
            IAsyncResult result = _client.BeginConnect(ipAddr, port, null, null);

            WaitHandle timeoutHandler = result.AsyncWaitHandle;

            try 
            {
                if (!result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(AppSettings.Instance.ConnectTimeout), false))
                {
                    _client.Close();
                    _connected = false;
                    log.Info("Timeout connecting to " + _listenType);
                } else 
                {
                    //log.Info("Connected to " + _listenType);
                    _client.EndConnect(result);
                    _stream = _client.GetStream();
                    //_stream.ReadTimeout = AppSettings.Instance.ReadTimeout*1000;
                    _connected = true;
                }
            } 
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                _connected = false;
                log.Error("Error connecting to " + _listenType + ". Error: " + ex.Message, ex);
            } 
            finally 
            {
                timeoutHandler.Close();
            }

            if (!_connected) 
            {
                srvInd++;
                if (srvInd >= addr.Length)
                {
                    srvInd = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        if (_running && _connected) 
        {
            Subscribe();
        }
    }

    protected void SendString(string str) 
    {
        var buf = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str + "\r\n");
        _stream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
    }

    private string FixPattern(string code) 
    {
        return code.Replace("*", "\\*");
    }

    private void Subscribe() {
        _lastSubscribe = DateTime.Now;

        if (_listenType == "USSD")
        {
            //Subscribe to USSD service
            SendString("<usereq USERNAME='" + _username + "' PASSWORD ='" + _password + "' VERBOSITY='0'>");
            SendString("<subscribe NODE='.*' TRANSFORM='USSD' PATTERN='\\*'/>");
            SendString("</usereq>END");

            log.Info("Subscription to USSD - Connected - " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
        }
        else if (_listenType == "ACCOUNTS")
        {
            SendString("<usereq USERNAME='" + _username + "' PASSWORD ='" + _password + "'>");
            //MTN_Accounts_SendString("<subscribe NODE='pollSmppTopic' TRANSFORM='DELIVER_SM'>");
            SendString("<subscribe NODE='" + _username + "' TRANSFORM='DELIVER_SM'>");
            SendString("<pattern><![CDATA[$short_message~='.*']]></pattern>");
            SendString("</subscribe>");
            SendString("</usereq>END");

            log.Info("Subscription to Accounts (" + _username + ") - Connected - " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
        }
    }

    private bool Eol(byte[] buf) {
        if (buf.Length < 1) {
            return false;
        }
        return buf[buf.Length - 1] == 0x0a;
    }

    protected string ReadString() 
    {
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        while (!Eol(ms.ToArray())) 
        {
            try 
            {
                byte[] buf = new byte[1];
                int len = _stream.Read(buf, 0, 1);
                if (len > 0) 
                {
                    ms.WriteByte(buf[0]);
                }
                else 
                {
                    break;
                }
            } 
            catch(IOException) 
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (ms.Length==0) 
        {
            return null;
        }
        return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ms.ToArray()).TrimEnd(new char[] { '\r', '\n' });
    }

    private void ListenerThreadProc() 
    {
        _connected = false;
        while (_running) 
        {
            try 
            {
                if (!_connected) 
                {
                    //log.Info("_listenType + ("+ _username + ") - Disconnected. Attempting to reconnect. DateTime: " + DateTime.Now);
                    Reconnect();
                }

                //log.Info(_listenType +" ("+ _username + ") - Total minutes elapsed since last refresh : " +DateTime.Now.Subtract(_lastSubscribe).TotalMinutes);

                if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(_lastSubscribe).TotalMinutes >= AppSettings.Instance.SubscribeInterval) 
                {
                    //log.Info(_listenType + " (" + _username + ") - Refreshing Thread : " + DateTime.Now.Subtract(_lastSubscribe).TotalMinutes);
                    EmailService sendMail = new EmailService();
                    sendMail.SendEmail("ADMIN", "ALERT - Message Manager : Re-subscribing to " + _listenType + " listening service", "", null, "");

                    Subscribe();
                }

                string line;
                string message = "";

                while ((line = ReadString()) != null)
                {
                    using (var fs = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath), AppSettings.Instance.MessageFilename), true)) 
                    {
                        fs.WriteLine(line);
                    }

                    log.Debug("Received: " + line);

                    if (line.Contains("<usarsp"))
                    {
                        message = "";
                        message = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>";
                        message = message + line;
                    }
                    else if (line.Contains("</usarsp>"))
                    {
                        message = message + line;

                        ProcessMTNMessage processMessage = new ProcessMTNMessage();
                        processMessage.processMessage(_listenType, message);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        message = message + line;
                    }
                }

                if(!_client.Connected) 
                {
                    _connected = false;
                    try 
                    {
                        _stream.Close();
                    } 
                    catch (Exception ex) 
                    {
                        log.Error("Exception Error: " + ex.Message, ex);
                    }
                }

                Thread.Sleep(100);
            } 
            catch(IOException) 
            {
                log.Info("Disconnected.");
                _connected = false;
                try 
                {
                    _stream.Close();
                } 
                catch (Exception ex) 
                {
                    log.Error("Exception Error: " + ex.Message, ex);
                }

                try 
                {
                    _client.Close();
                } 
                catch (Exception ex) 
                {
                    log.Error("Exception Error: " + ex.Message, ex);
                }
            } 
            catch(ThreadInterruptedException ex) 
            {
                log.Error("Thread Interrupted Error: " + ex.Message, ex);
            } 
            catch(Exception ex) 
            {
                log.Error("Exception Error: " + ex.Message, ex);
            }
        }

        if(_connected) 
        {
            try 
            {
                _stream.Close();
            } 
            catch(Exception ex) 
            {
                log.Error("Exception Error: " + ex.Message, ex);
            }
            try 
            {
                _client.Close();
            } 
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                log.Error("Exception Error: " + ex.Message, ex);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not [sending keepalive messages on a regular basis](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/05/detection-of-half-open-dropped.html); I describe this on my blog.

Also, I recommend that you either use synchronous (e.g., `Read`) or asynchronous (e.g., `BeginConnect`) methods, but not both. I usually recommend asynchronous methods; they are more difficult to code with but are more resilient.

Your [message framing](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html) (as I describe on my blog) is also incorrect; you're not properly handling the situation where two updates can arrive back-to-back.

To be blunt, almost everything about the code right now is wrong. I strongly recommend that you do not implement a custom TCP/IP protocol, since you really don't need one. Just use SignalR, WebAPI, or WCF, which handle the hard parts of protocols for you. Your code will end up much cleaner and more reliable.